# RecyclerView does not scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with a RecyclerView: it does not scroll, here's my layout:

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:cardElevation="1dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/square3"
            android:src="@drawable/square"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/nameeOfMonthTable"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recicloEvent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separatorDateRvCale2"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recicloEvent"

            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/separatorDateRvCale"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recicloEvent"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

this is the adapter of another RecyclerView that scrolls correctly:
the upper RecyclerView has inside another RecyclerView (the one that does not scroll correctly)
The problem affects only the inner table (that is the one up).
How can I solve this?
Here's a screen: [image: RecyclerView] , the problem affects the RecyclerView that is cut at the bottom

Comment: Problem in layout Design's code, please correct it.

Comment: height is 0 for recycler view

Comment: actually you something is missing in your above XML code (**CardView**) starting was missing.

Comment: upload you design which you want so we understand what you actually want

Comment: @Arbaz.in updated

Answer (score 1):

try putting the whole layout inside a NestedScrollView as follows

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/square3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/square" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separatorDateRvCale2"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separatorDateRvCale"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recicloEvent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/day"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameeOfMonthTable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of what you have so far?

Comment: i have changed some layouts in my answer. please try this new one

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recicloEvent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   //check this must be match_parent or wrap_content
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"/>
```

Comment: i have tried both of them but nothing happened, other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

just put this code in your `xml` file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/square" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/day"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameeOfMonthTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recicloEvent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lin"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separatorDateRvCale2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recicloEvent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3"

        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separatorDateRvCale"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/square3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recicloEvent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/square3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what was  issue  ?